# pandas - Tranche allocation with countdown

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have not been able to find an answer for this generic problem.

Let's assume the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'qty':[7,7,7], 'elt':['a','b','c'], 'limit':[2,4,100]})

df
   qty elt  limit
0    7   a      2
1    7   b      4
2    7   c    100
```

In which 'qty' denotes the total quantity to allocate. Each element 'elt' represents a tranche and has a limit of quantity it can support. I want to determine how much quantity needs to be allocated against each element constrained by the limit.

The resulting dataframe should be:

```
df
   qty elt  limit  allocation
0    7   a      2           2
1    7   b      4           4
2    7   c    100           1
```

Any advice on how to do this? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check with `np.where` with `cumsum`

```
df['allocation']=np.where(df.limit.cumsum()<=df.qty,df.limit,df.qty-df.limit.cumsum().shift())
df
Out[806]: 
   qty elt  limit  allocation
0    7   a      2         2.0
1    7   b      4         4.0
2    7   c    100         1.0
```